# 12.04 sound keeps auto-muting when idle

Tags: 12.04, sound, hp, mute

I just installed 12.04 on an HP8510W. Everything works fine except for one weird behavior which I have noticed. When ever there is no audio playing, the audio mute indicator on the laptop is on. As soon as I start playing a you tube video the mute indicator turns off and I get sound.

Here is my pulse audio output which says that the sink is suspended because it is idle:

```
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
```

I tried running `alsamixer`, but I don't see the auto-mute option.

Answer (score 5):

To stop pulseaudio from suspending a sink when idle we may comment out (by adding `#`) the following line in our `default.pa` (located in `/etc/pulse/`, or in `~/.pulse`) to look like follows:

```
 # load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

Restart the pulseaudio server to take effect (by running `pulseaudio -k` in a terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` to contain the following:

```
# load the default system configuration 
.include /etc/pulse/default.pa
# ignore errors and continue startup
.nofail
unload-module module-suspend-on-idle
# re-enable failure on errors
.fail
```